# Android lollipop Wi-Fi murders battery

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life, 5.1-lollipop

I have an unrooted galaxy S6, Verizon, and Android 5.1.1 on it.Each night I fully charge my phone,  and it never leaves my pocket after 6 am or gets used until 2 pm. At 2, the battery may be around 90% or it may be at 50% without any use. I discovered the battery was much lower if I had Wi-Fi on,  even though I was never connected to Wi-Fi. Battery chart in settings says Google services or Google play services used all the battery.Please help,  I've tried everything I can think of,  and I'm usually good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play services runs in the background to keep applications up to date and to sync your information to Google.

- One possible cause of the battery drain could be if you have **multiple accounts** on your device. Your device will drain more battery to keep up with the demands on the services
- Another possible cause of the battery drain could be a third-party application running in the background and using data from Google Play services

To fix either of these problems, you may want to boot your phone into **Safe Mode**. This will ensure that the Google Play services or anything else that could drain the battery aren't running. But at the same time, you can freely use Wi-Fi or any application that you choose to run.

### To boot into Safe Mode:

- Turn off your device and wait about 2 minutes
- Once it is off, hold down the **power button** and the **volume down button**. You may release the power button when you see the screen turn on, but **do not** release the power button until the phone is completely turned on.

(Google Play services battery drain is from [this](https://www.androidpit.com/google-play-services-battery-drain-how-to-fix-it) source)

Comment: Does S6 have a hardware button combo dedicated for safe mode as well as recovery mode? Are you certain that you meant safe mode and not recovery mode? Safe mode,often can only be accessed when device is rebooted into it from Android's power menu.

Comment: It is definitely Safe Mode. I tried it, since I have an S6 myself.

Comment: I see. So how does it look like? Can you explain what difference do you seen in normal mode and what you refer to as safe mode? Sorry, my clarification may appear to be intimidating but I'm only trying to know something here.

Comment: Everything on the phone is displayed as if it came right out of the box: it temporarily resets the current theme, icon placements, and makes the applications that are not pre-installed with the phone unavailable. It would be useful for this case, in which the person wouldn't be using it (so the reduced functionality wouldn't be a problem)

Comment: I rebooted into safe mode (accessed power menu and held the power off option) . I had all day with Wi-Fi on,  and battery was like it usually is with Wi-Fi off. So I'll try all of the methods to reduce Google services battery usage. I'll report back with the results tomorrow.

Comment: After several days, I still don't know what the problem is. I do have two accounts, but sync is completely off on one and minimal on the other. Is WiFi battery usage part of Google (play) services? WiFi seems to be what triggers the battery hit